# Run two CMD service in a Dockerfile

Tags: docker

I would like to ask if it's possible to run 2 CMD command. I know we can't, if we put 2 CMD command it will only execute the last one. Here is what I tried :

```
CMD bash /start-script.sh && /usr/bin/supervisord -c /etc/supervisord.conf
```

But it doesn't run the both service.

Here is the seperated `CMD`

```
CMD ["/start-script.sh"]
ENTRYPOINT [ "/entrypoint.sh" ]
CMD [ "/usr/bin/supervisord", "-c", "/etc/supervisord.conf" ]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please think about what you are planning to do here, as your approach is somewhat outside of the best practices with Docker.

In short out of the docker best practices: You should not start two applications, but only one in a docker container. This advice makes sense, as docker stops the container when the one application exits. If you have more than one, you are basically screwed.

However ...
There are workarounds which can help you:

- The simple ones are: start single shell script, which starts both application and then goes into a never ending loop.
- use a solution like supervisord which allows handling several applications/services in parallel.

The documentation to both solutions can be found here: https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/multi-service_container/

My personal preference would be using shared volumes and separate docker container. (you can still glue them together with docker-compose). Using that you have full control over each application and it is pretty simple and straight forward.